# source $HOME/.bashrc conflicts with zsh?

Tags: command-line, bashrc, zsh

When I do `source $HOME/.bashrc`, it results in the following:

[image: screenshot]

As you can see, it jumbles up the text where the path of the current directory would be. I am calling this because I am trying to change the colors of the directories when using ls, but it only works when I `source .bashrc`.

Comment: You can skip the first part of my answer if you don't want to use the default `zshrc` setup. The rest of the answer will still work but you will need to restart `zsh` to get rid of the jumbled up text.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Before you begin, exit out of `zsh` and then run the `zsh` command. You should get a prompt that asks you to make a selection. Press <kbd>2</kbd>. This will create a default `~/.zshrc` file.</sub>

---

**Files with the "rc" suffix are called [run-control files](http://www.catb.org/~esr/writings/taoup/html/ch10s03.html)¹.**

[`bash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/bash.1.html) uses a `~/.bashrc` file for configuring your bash session and [`zsh`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/zsh.1.html) uses a `~/.zshrc` file.

The `ls` configuration in your `bashrc` file uses "aliases". Run the following command to show all of your `ls` aliases:

```
cat ~/.bashrc | grep "alias.*ls"
```

Now, to transfer those aliases to your `~/.zshrc` file, run the following commands:

```
cat ~/.bashrc | grep "alias.*ls" >> ~/.zshrc
. ~/.zshrc
```

<sub>**Note:** `. ~/.zshrc` is the same as `source ~/.zshrc` but with less typing.</sub>

---

You can do the same thing for `grep`:

```
cat ~/.bashrc | grep "alias.*grep" >> ~/.zshrc
. ~/.zshrc
```

¹<sub>inherited from "[rc file](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/R/rc-file.html)" used on older Unix systems</sub>

Comment: Different syntax is sometimes used for zsh and bash. See the section "prompt" in [this detailed answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/361957/90181) for the customized prompt differences.